# Is it OK to use "Know" at the end of the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

For example,

> My Question: Why are you not taking any leaves nowadays.
>   My colleague's reply: I am in notice period **know**.

Is it OK to use "Know" at the end of the sentence? Is it acceptable?

Comment: Are you from India ?

Comment: What are you trying to say with **know**? For you sentence it seems you mean **now**

Comment: It's either **, you know** or **now**, otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: I think you wanted to say *you know.*

Comment: Yes Varun. I am from India.

Comment: I think '**you know**' was misheard because sometimes, it's pronounced like, '**y'know**', making it difficult to be distinguished (likely if the listener's not used to hearing it).

Answer (score 1):

I have two guesses. My first guess is that you have probably misheard the colleague. The correct form is "you know".

> My Question: Why are you not taking any leaves nowadays?
>   My colleague's reply: I am in my notice period, **you know**.

From [The Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/you-know):

> We use **you know** very commonly in speaking. It is used to check with our listeners that we share the same knowledge. When we use you know, we assume that the listener or listeners do have the knowledge that we want them to have:
>
> *Well, what can I say, **you know**, I want my career to go far.*
>
> *A: How was the match?*
>   *B: Well, they played OK but the defence was, **you know**, the same as always.*
>
> **You know** is also sometimes used to allow us time to think when we are speaking:
>
> *A: Did you like the play?*
>
> *B: Well, I’m not sure, it was, **you know**, it was interesting.*

The dictionary has a nice page on [discourse markers](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/discourse-markers-so-right-okay).

---

My second guess is that if it's not **you know**, then it might be **now**. If it's just **know**, it seems to make no sense in that position.

With **now**, the dialogue looks like this:

> My Question: Why are you not taking any leaves nowadays.
>   My colleague's reply: I am in my notice period **now**.